# ROR + Ruby Function To Access Last Value Of An Variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In `Ruby 1.8.6`, I want to the last value of any string.

For example : `notice_5` here, I want `"5"` in one of the variable. So please suggest any function through which I can get 5 in one of the variable.

Thanks

Comment: SOlution found and written below.

Answer (score 1):

Use index *-1*

```
var = "somevar_5"
var[0]
 => "s"
var[-1]       # get character code
 => 53
var[-1].chr   #get character
 => "5"
```

Comment: Thanks, I got the solution ie mention in answer

Comment: You get a Fixnum from `string[n]` in 1.8, in 1.9 you get another String.

Answer (score 0):

Got the Solution

```
>> a = 'hello_7'
=> "hello_7"
>> a.last
=> "7"
```

Comment: Does this actually work? I don't think `String` has a `last` method.

Comment: `String` hasn't `last` method in ruby. Rails extend String with `ActiveSupport`.

Comment: Ah, OK. I've just spotted the `ruby-on-rails` tag on your question. The `last` method is actually added by Rails ActiveSupport and isn't a standard Ruby method on Strings.

Comment: @antonversal yep, just realised the same thing and was writing another comment at the same time :)